# Install MySQL in Google Colab

Tags: mysql, google-colaboratory

I have been successfully installing and using MySQL in Google Colab with this code for quite some time.

```
# install, set connection
!apt-get install mysql-server > /dev/null
!service mysql start
!mysql -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root'"
!pip -q install PyMySQL
%load_ext sql
%config SqlMagic.feedback=False 
%config SqlMagic.autopandas=True
%sql mysql+pymysql://root:root@/
```

However now I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I tried to connect without password:

```
%sql mysql+pymysql://root:@/
```

But I get the SQLAlchemy format error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```